# Properties fileNotFoundException in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, filenotfoundexception, properties-file

i have a **properties file** names config.properties in path: src/main/resources/config.properties, but when i try to **launch** the job i get Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
[image: exception trace]

[image]

Before was working but suddenly not, and i don't know
thanks and sorry for my english is not my native languaje

I belive that the error is produced becouse i have in pom.xml a exclude for when generate jar the config not included but i dont underestand i get this exception

Comment: Let's so us how are you reading your config file ?

Comment: i read with propertySource -> @Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")

Comment: could you restart your ide once and try again?

Comment: i restart but not working, i change the name canfig -> configuration and now it working, but i woant not cgange name constantly

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me:

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config.properties");
```

This method is designed to find anything under the `resources` folder. Be careful, as it...

> ...Does not check whether the file actually exists; simply returns the File that the given location would correspond to.

So, make sure to check whether the File is empty or not.

Comment: Hi, currently several ways are working but i don't know why mi code work and founds the properties file and another day not working yet.